# optimizing simple mysql query

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have a very simple query:

```
SELECT cp.`id_connections`
FROM `connections_page` cp
WHERE cp.`time_end` IS NULL
AND TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), cp.`time_start`)) < 900
GROUP BY cp.`id_connections`
```

for a very simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ps_connections_page` (
`id_connections` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`id_page` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`time_start` datetime NOT NULL,
`time_end` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id_connections`,`id_page`,`time_start`),
KEY `time_end` (`time_end`),
KEY `id_connections` (`id_connections`),
KEY `id_page` (`id_page`),
KEY `time_start` (`time_start`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

with about **2.5 millions rows**, and it **takes between 2 and 6 seconds** to execute (mysql 5.1.54-log)

and **EXPLAIN EXTENDED** says:

```
id      select_type    table    type    possible_keys   key         key_len ref     rows    filtered    Extra
1       SIMPLE         cp       ref     time_end        time_end    9       const   1497890 100.00      Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Looking at execution plan, there is something wrong with index usage, but I can't figure it out. So: how can I do to speed up this query **witohut changing data structure** (I can change query and / or indexes, but not columns)?

Comment: First of all: Why do you define 3 Primary keys? What's your intention? Are you showing this on a report page? Why do you want to optimize it?

Comment: @wegginho  it takes between 2 and 6 seconds why wouldn't you modify it ?

Comment: @wegginho I am trying to optimize it because it takes too much time. Original table had only PRIMARY KEY (`id_connections`,`id_page`,`time_start`). I added anothers in hope that it will help, but there is no difference (looks like mysql do nothing with those indexes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part:

```
TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), cp.`time_start`)) < 900
```

Cannot use the index on `time_start` because the latter is part of the expression. If you want the query to be able to use that index, you'll need to rewrite it accordingly:

```
time_start < something_constant
```

Also, you might benefit by adding the index on several of the where/group by fields:

```
key(time_start, time_end, id_connections)
```

Comment: It's all about using indexes and expressions. "cp.`time_start` > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 900 SECOND)" with index (time_start, time_end, id_connections) added works like a charm - I have execution times like 0.0001 sec. now (compared to +/- 5 seconds before) . I've definitely learned something today, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

first you don't need to use alias cp

second I would try doing a sub select to reduce the time calculations

try this out let me know if it makes a difference

```
SELECT id_connections
FROM (SELECT id_connections FROM connections_page WHERE time_end IS NULL))
WHERE TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), time_start)) < 900
GROUP BY id_connections
```

Comment: I convinced mysql to execute: "SELECT z.id_connections
FROM (SELECT id_connections, time_start
FROM connections_page WHERE time_end IS NULL) AS z
WHERE TIME_TO_SEC( TIMEDIFF( NOW( ), z.time_start ) ) <900
GROUP BY z.id_connections" , but there is no difference (it's using index on time_end, but that's all)